# getClass() in Java versus javaClass in Kotlin (error when converting code from Java to Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I want to convert code written in Java to Kotlin. IntelliJ handled most things but there is a problem with the following snippet and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code written in Java:
And the error only appears in two places:

in the function `createCsv`: in `row.javaClass` it shows this fragment in red - there is no such function in Kotlin in Java in this place there was `row.getClass()` I tried to make `row.javaClass.kotlin` or `row.javaClass.simpleName` there, but it doesn't work.

According to the documentation: [https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)](https://stackoverflow.com)

There is no implementation of `convertValue(Any, Any)`, but somehow it automatically converts to Any for me and I don't know too much how it should look like, which is the same as in Java.

Answer (score 2):

`row.javaClass` is the correct equivalent of `row.getClass()`. The problem here is different: `row` is potentially nullable, so you can't invoke anything on it directly, without checking if it is null.

If you assume `rows` can only contain non-null values, you have to define your functions like this:

```kotlin
private fun <T : Any> createCsvSchema(...)
```

If it may contain nulls, you have to handle a null case inside `map { ... }`.